# Unable to read csv pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am having trouble reading csv using spark.read.csv - I am not sure what wrong with this particular location I am getting null pointer exceptions error. When I read other csv files it looks fine . Anyone faced similar issues . Please let me know

```
[]$ hdfs dfs -ls /hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/Inbound/tmp/.TEST/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   3 qweqweqw hadoop          0 2021-04-30 16:24 /hdfsData/poc/Inbound/tmp/.TEST/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 qweqweqw hadoop   10091562 2021-04-30 16:24 /hdfsData/poc/qweqweqw/tmp/.TEST/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file/part-00000-4a4cd500-4e34-4403-a75f-61e09210f9ee-c000.csv
-rw-r--r--   3 qweqweqw hadoop   11237536 2021-04-30 16:24 /hdfsData/poc/Inbound/tmp/.TEST/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file/part-00000-ee9ad347-14ef-42a6-ab20-3ac329b9ce71-c000.csv

    $ pyspark
    Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2020, 02:51:10)
    [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    Setting default log level to "WARN".
    To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
    21/05/03 12:43:40 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
    21/05/03 12:43:40 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
    21/05/03 12:43:40 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4042. Attempting port 4043.
    Welcome to
          ____              __
         / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
        _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
       /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.2.3.1.5.0-152
          /_/
    
    Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2020 02:51:10)
    SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> spark.read.csv("/hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/Inbound/tmp/.TEST/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file/*.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 441, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o132.csv.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.length(ArrayOps.scala:192)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.zipWithIndex(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.zipWithIndex(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVDataSource.makeSafeHeader(CSVDataSource.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.inferFromDataset(CSVDataSource.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.infer(CSVDataSource.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVDataSource.inferSchema(CSVDataSource.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:203)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:393)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:596)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The file was created by another spark process and read in this step for processing . Will folders have . cause any issue ? or is it anything basic I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code where you save your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the path with file system. Try giving full qualified path with file system, like `spark.read.csv("hdfs:///hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/Inbound/tmp/.TEST/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file/*.csv")`

Update:
To use regex pattern,

`spark.read.csv("hdfs:///hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/Inbound/tmp/.TEST/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file/[part-]*.csv")`

Comment: Dont think thats is the problem
>>> >>> spark.read.csv("hdfs://hostname/hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/Inbound/hifitmp/.HIFI/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file/part-00000-4a4cd500-4e34-4403-a75f-61e09210f9ee-c000.csv")
DataFrame[_c0: string]
>>> spark.read.csv("hdfs://hostname/hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/Inbound/hifitmp/.HIFI/23329_20210430_162409/src_copy_file.file/part-*.csv")py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o76.csv.
: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I guess that is not a valid regex in 2nd use. Please use [part-]*.csv

Comment: The file reading is written using spark.write.text . When reading a spark.write.text written file with spark.read.csv its throwing some error. The same file is read if read as spark.read.text